# Component scan in java config and xml config loading in different context heirarchy?

Tags: spring

I have to import java spring config into the xml config. So i have imported the java config as below.

```
<bean class="ApplicationConfig" />
```

This java config has component scan with a base package say 'A.B.C'

We had the same component scan config in the xml as well. So, instead of defining the same in two places, i have removed it from the xml.

But my code didnt work. Once i have readded the same component scan in xml config, it worked.

My question is why I had to add component scan in xml as well, when the same component scan defined in my java config.?

Comment: If you remove component scan you are removing the annotation driven approach. When removing the `<context:component-scan />` you have to add `<context:annotation-config />` else your `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan` don't do anything.

Comment: Are you sure ApplicationConfig is picked up? It is not in a package?

Comment: I am not sure, what happened. i have removed all the xml config with java config. then it worked.